# Delete multiple rows by ticking Checkbox

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, delete-row

How do I delete multiple rows by checking a checkbox?
I have a table of records, and I'd like to to delete multiple rows at once.

This is my my deleteselected function:

**UPDATED**

```
 public function order() {


if(!empty($this->data)) {
        //If at lesst 1 check box is selected
        if (isset($this->data) && !empty($this->data['order_id'])) {
            $selectedReferences = $this->data['order_id'];

            $flagReferenceAdded = false;
            foreach ($selectedReferences as $singleReference) {
                //NEW DELETE
                $this->Order->id = $singleReference;
                $this->Order->delete();
                //NEW DELETE
            }
            //After delete
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('Your All record Are deleted.')
            );
            return $this->redirect(array(''));
        }      
        else{
            echo "Select at least 1 ORDER.";
        }  
}
```

and in my view.

```
  <?php
         echo $this->Form->create('Order',array('url' => array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'order'))); ?>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>phone</th>
                    <th>view</th>
                    <th>delete</th>
            <thead>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <?php foreach ($order as $orders): ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $orders['Order']['varfullname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $orders['Order']['varemailid']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $orders['Order']['varphone']; ?></td>
                     <td>
<?php echo $this->Html->link('',
array('controller' => 'orders', 'action' => 'view', $orders['Order']['id']), array('title'=>'VIEW','class' => 'fa fa-search'));?>

</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value ="<?php echo $orders['Order']['id'];?>" hiddenField = "false">
                </td>
                </tr>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>

</br>

          <?
echo $this->Form->end('Deleteselected'); ?> 
    </div>
</div>
</br>

</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

after using below answer my delete selected working fine 
[image]

Comment: You again :) Ok AGAIN here also you didnt give PROPER details . OK . What doperation u do on  checkbox.Give Screenshot of page.How are  you deleting Records ? By checking checkbox and then Delete button .Everything is UNCLEAR so noone can answer your Question

Comment: above is deleteall action and its working fine but i want to delete. selected records only.

Comment: hi I said : `What doperation u do on checkbox.Give Screenshot of page.How are you deleting Records ? By checking checkbox and then Delete button `. So edit Question and ADD DETAILS

Comment: ya right now i delete records 1 by 1 but i want to use checkbox. tocheck multiple records and when i click on delete that time i want to delete selected check box records..

Comment: WHY THE HELL you have 1000 delete buttons??(1 in EACH ROW) ?? USE only 1 Button called **`DELETE`** And it will delete Records which are ticked using CHECKBOX . WHY dont u use paperwork And Logic before making Code ??

Comment: k i want only 1 Button called DELETE And it will delete Records which are ticked using CHECKBOX..! means if i checked 4 records then it will delete that 4 recors only.

Comment: Yes now u got my point . I answer ,wait 4 min\

Comment: On a side note, you are creating nested forms, that's not allwed in HTML and won't work. If you'd need to use `postLink()` in another form (which you don't for your delete selected functionality), then make use of the `inline` option so that the forms are created in the post link view block. **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use in ctp

//in ctp Along with EACH record use Checkbox integration . Dont use Checkbox code u used.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value ="<?php echo $referenceSingle['Order']['id'];?>" hiddenField = "false">
```

//In controller

```
if(!empty($this->data)) {
        //If at lesst 1 check box is selected
        if (isset($this->data) && !empty($this->data['order_id'])) {
            $selectedReferences = $this->data['order_id'];

            $flagReferenceAdded = false;
            foreach ($selectedReferences as $singleReference) {
                //NEW DELETE
                $this->Order->id = $singleReference;
                $this->Order->delete();
                //NEW DELETE
            }
            //After delete
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('Your All record Are deleted.')
            );
            return $this->redirect(array(''));
        }      
        else{
            echo "Select at least 1 ORDER.";
        }  
}
```

**UPDATE**

Use Above Code in your Index method itself ,Dont create deleteAll method.

OR
Make `<form action` TO deleteAll

LIKE
    `echo $this->Form->create('searchCourse',array('url' => array('controller' => 'Courses', 'action' => 'index')));`

**UPDATE**
For proper Workflow refer :
[image]
ALWAYS do paperwork and Algorithm ,Before Coding SIR.

Comment: its new ..same table when i check and then when i click on delete selected nothing hapen page refresh only. above is updated image

Comment: Dude , you are making me cry on your Issue.This is simple.See I said ,USE only 1 DELETE button.I CAN SEE 10000000000000 delete buttons (1 in EACH row) in Screenshot.I SAID : There should be one DELETE button only only after listing of all ROWS.Do u get it?

Comment: ok i will use only 1 delete button. ya but i want checkbox to working fine as well as in header select all checkbox too :D

Comment: One minute . You are not deleting 1 row at a time OK? You are deleting Multiple rows at a time ,So why did u use multiple delete buttons ?? What was ur logic? OK as per your WRONG LOGIC , I select 1,2,3 Order and now Click on delete button of 7th Record .So WHAT should happen ????????????Whether 7th record should be deleted or 3,4th ???? USe logic dude

Comment: ya this logic i already know. this delete button in image are for delete functon.  i have delete selected button in below. which delete all selected field. ok as per your suggetion i delete that delete button ok tell me check box solution.

Comment: DUDE LAST time i m telling You : UPDATE Question by Putting recent code I gave you And u used.I gave Checkbox Code like `<input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value ="<?php echo $referenceSingle['Order']['id'];?>" hiddenField = "false">` .AND I CANT SEE IN YOUR UPDATED Code. GETTING??????

Comment: k i delete delete fun. and  create only 1  button and it will working fine after using your login now i want to select all checkbox from table head.. tell me logic of it thanks. :)

Comment: @newsurt ,Helo is it working ,by selecting Checkboxes and Clicking on Sinlge delete Button?

Comment: ya.. its working. if i select 1 records and click on delete submit then it will delete 1 as well if i select 2 then it will delte 2 thanks 

now i want in `<th>` that select all checkbox. option thanks